# Creating a Limited Privilege PostgreSQL Role for Backend Server

Tags: postgresql, security, privileges, access-control

I am trying to create a role in postgres for the backend server and for security reasons I want to limit the backend_user privileges. The user have access only to database_x and the public schema and can do the following in all tables in database_x:

- add/create a row
- modify/update a row
- delete a row

the user **cannot** do the following

- create a new DB, table or colunm in a table
- drop a DB, table or column in a table
- modify a DB, table, or column in a table ( for example modifying the name )

I have followed [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) but all attempts have been unsuccessful.

EDIT:

```
CREATE user userx WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mypass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO userx;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO userx;
grant all PRIVILEGES on all tables in schema public to userx;

REVOKE drop, alter ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM userx;
REVOKE alter, create, drop ON DATABASE mydb FROM userx;
```

Comment: I shared the code. I failed to limit the access control policies as I stated before. The user created can still do prohibited actions like add drop a table or a column with the code above.

Comment: Where do you see `DROP` or `ALTER` here [Grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) or here [Grant privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html)? Basically if a user has the privileges to `CREATE` something they also can `DROP`  or `ALTER` that thing. In other words what you want is not possible.

Comment: That's what I am trying to achieve. The user has the privileges to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE rows on tables and revoke everything else. So the user cannot create, drop, alter a database or tables.

Comment: @Atmo. No, the question has *the user cannot do the following ... drop a DB, table or column in a table modify a DB, table, or column in a table ( for example modifying the name )*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver You say "*if the user has the privileges to `CREATE` something*". Sorry but where is it mentioned userx should have the `CREATE` privilege? "*create a new DB, table or colunm in a table*" is also in the "userx **cannot**" category. As to what "*create a row*", most likely, it just means `INSERT`....

Comment: Then you want `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO userx;` and `GRANT ALL USAGE  ON SCHEMA public TO userx;` and `grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on all tables in schema public to userx;`. And don't do the `REVOKE`'s

Comment: @Atmo. Here: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO userx;` That includes `CREATE` which for a schema is: *For schemas, allows new objects to be created within the schema. To rename an existing object, you must own the object and have this privilege for the containing schema.*

Comment: You need to read the links I posted in my first comment. There is a lot going on in there and you will probably need to go the text several times to take it all in. I know I still go back to it figure things out.

Comment: Of course.... the whole point of the question is that the commands don't do what the OP wants. Anyway, the reason I was not providing an answer myself was because I was wondering if privileges granted to `PUBLIC` could interfere. Can't recall how to check that from the top of my head though.

Comment: @Atmo read the information here [Grant privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html). The part that starts *PostgreSQL grants privileges on some types of objects to PUBLIC by default ...*

Comment: That paragraph applies to new objects. What I was wondering was: OP is not creating new objects here but a new role. Could it be possible `PUBLIC` can create tables, and `userx` automatically get the privilege too when it gets created.

Comment: Read [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html): *Any particular role will have the sum of privileges granted directly to it, privileges granted to any role it is presently a member of, and privileges granted to PUBLIC.* As I commented to the the OP, you need to read the information contained at both links thoroughly. This is a complex subject, just skimming the docs is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Adrian Klaver the solution that worked:

```
CREATE user userx WITH ENCRYPTED password 'password';

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO userx;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO userx;
grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on all tables in schema public to userx;
```

The user cannot create, modify, delete a database, a table or a column in a table.